# how to deal with the EMI issues in the 16X2 LCD display?

Tags: lcd, emc

I'm designing a product with 16X2 LCD display and it shows the junk characters when i switch the 3-phase contactor ON/OFF through the relay.How to solve this issue through software or hardware redesign?

Comment: why are you switching off a small LCD (microamperes of current) with a relay? that is a very uncommon thing to do.

Comment: check Analog bias voltages ripple on LCD and use all EMC principles to reduce emissions of source and attenuate noise from coupling by induction. CM chokes, shielding, ferrite beads etc. use proper Probe with gnd inductance removed.  Arc noise is very high current and voltage EMI over entire band.  Can you blank display during transition?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I have searched for the solutions for the LCD issue in the most of the forums but at the end no proper solution for the problem. so i thought some one with the experience of EMI/EMC could help me with suggestions. How do LCD display pass EMI/EMC test?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not switching LCD display using relay. The LCD displays junk character when i switch on the relay

Comment: @yogece you need to show us far more of your design if we are to help. We need schematics and PCB layout. Add them to your Question.

Comment: Use low ESR caps across DC voltages, use shield cables with Ferrite sleeve around long cables and route at right angles. Avoid proximity effects near contactors. Use shorted scope probe to measure transients. and sniff for noise near circuit and move away from noise. Without your layout and design details , no further advice possible.,

Comment: Thank you so much @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 this problem is faced almost everyone who uses LCD display in their product.Can you share your debugging suggestions as an answer so that it would be useful for all and I think so only most of the temperature controller products uses 7 segment displays https://blog.adafruit.com/2012/12/31/industrial-pid-temperature-controller-teardown/

Comment: Since you have high impedances and antenna loops involved the problem is to reduce 3ph DC current EMI noise at source with shielding & snubbers then reduce coupling at instruments.

Comment: Concentrate on what is happening at the contactor. The contactor is most likely switching an inductive load, and the coil of the contactor is also an inductive load. You need to suppress the inductive spikes that occur at BOTH places (diodes, snubbers, MOVs, etc. ... whatever is appropriate).

Comment: @SteveG LCD is placed directly on the PCB using berg stick connectors (cable is not used to connect them). I think the problem is elsewhere its not with the PCB; it might be due to EFT(Electric Fast Transient) or some strange thing

Comment: sniff with a shorted scope probe to act as a loop antenna for spikes and see for yourself what you get using probe as antenna

Comment: you need to add all the information you're giving in the comments to the question itself by **editing** it, @yogece!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You solve this with better design, of course.

Look particularly at the ground.  Make sure the large power currents of the motor are not running thru the low power part of the circuit, like the LCD and the microcontroller driving it.

A snubber across the motor might help.

Make sure the power to the logic part is clean.  Go back and add those bypass caps all those EE weenies are always on about.  They have a purpose, and now you've found it.

You may need a Schottky diode in series followed by a cap to ground at the immediate power input.  That protects your circuit from short negative glitches on the power.

Make sure the micro's reset input is not floating.

All in all, follow normal proper design practices, which of course you should have been doing in the first place.  You got sloppy and got caught.  Learn from this and pay attention to these details from now on.

A better answer requires a better question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to solve this in hardware.

You could try improving the quality of the relay you are using to switch the contactor, or alternatively power the relay from a completely separate supply and opto-isolate the drive. You can (and should) add a snubber to the coil of the contactor.

Also, if your LCD display has a ribbon cable, try to surround the display-ribbon cable-MCU  board with a Faraday cage that is solidly grounded  to the MCU ground.

EMI problems are never easy to fix with band-aid solutions.